# Seeking ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer Sample

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to use ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer to show a cached set of image tiles on our local server. There is good help on the [arcgis developer's site](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer.html) but I can't seem to find good examples. None of the samples they list actually call this method.

I'm using esri javascript api version 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample page.  Just replace the url to the Utah map service with the url of your tiled map service:

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/layers_ags_tiled.html

Comment: Thanks! do you know what the difference is between the ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer and the TiledMapServiceLayer?

Comment: @user1634292 TiledMapServiceLayer is the parent class of ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer. If you're using tiled arcgis server services, use ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer. TiledMapServiceLayer is also the parent class for a few other classes in the API:  WMTSLayer, OpenStreetMapLayer, WebTiledLayer.